# Show that $\{x^2, y^2, z^2, xy, xz, yz\}$ are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P^k$ be the space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $k$. If

$$P^2 = \mbox{span}\{x^2, y^2, z^2, xy, xz, yz\}$$

how and **why** could I show that the elements of $\mbox{span}$ are linearly independent? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should consider e.g. to show that the vectors of $\text{span}\{(1, 0, 0)^T, (0, 1, 0)^T, (1,0,1)^T\}$ are linearly independent first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that
$$
f(x,y,z)=
\lambda_1 x^2+\lambda_2 y^2+\lambda_3 z^2+\lambda_4 xy+\lambda_5 xz+\lambda_6 yz
$$
is the zero polynomial. Then
$$
f(1,0,0)=f(0,1,0)=f(0,0,1)=f(1,1,0)=f(1,0,1)=f(0,1,1)=0
$$
which gives the system of equations
\begin{array}{rcrcrcrcrcrcrcrcrcrc}
1\cdot \lambda_1 & + & 0\cdot \lambda_2 & + & 0\cdot \lambda_3 & + & 0\cdot \lambda_4 & + & 0\cdot \lambda_5 & + & 0\cdot \lambda_6 & = & 0 \\
0\cdot \lambda_1 & + & 1\cdot \lambda_2 & + & 0\cdot \lambda_3 & + & 0\cdot \lambda_4 & + & 0\cdot \lambda_5 & + & 0\cdot \lambda_6 & = & 0 \\
0\cdot \lambda_1 & + & 0\cdot \lambda_2 & + & 1\cdot \lambda_3 & + & 0\cdot \lambda_4 & + & 0\cdot \lambda_5 & + & 0\cdot \lambda_6 & = & 0 \\
1\cdot \lambda_1 & + & 1\cdot \lambda_2 & + & 0\cdot \lambda_3 & + & 1\cdot \lambda_4 & + & 0\cdot \lambda_5 & + & 0\cdot \lambda_6 & = & 0 \\
1\cdot \lambda_1 & + & 0\cdot \lambda_2 & + & 1\cdot \lambda_3 & + & 0\cdot \lambda_4 & + & 1\cdot \lambda_5 & + & 0\cdot \lambda_6 & = & 0 \\
0\cdot \lambda_1 & + & 1\cdot \lambda_2 & + & 1\cdot \lambda_3 & + & 0\cdot \lambda_4 & + & 0\cdot \lambda_5 & + & 1\cdot \lambda_6 & = & 0 
\end{array}
The coefficient matrix of this system is
$$
A=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
Row reducing gives
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref A=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
This shows that
$$
\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=\lambda_4=\lambda_5=\lambda_6=0
$$
Hence $\{x^2,y^2,z^2,xy,xz,yz\}$ is linearly independent.

To show that $\{x^2,y^2,z^2,xy,xz,yz\}$ spans $P^2$, note that by definition $P^2$ is spanned by monomials $x^ay^bz^c$. But the monomial $x^ay^bz^c$ is in $P^2$ if and only if $a+b+c=2$. The only solutions are
\begin{align*}
(a,b,c) &= (2,0,0) & (a,b,c) &= (0,2,0) & (a,b,c) &= (0,0,2) \\
(a,b,c) &= (1,1,0) & (a,b,c) &= (1,0,1) & (a,b,c) &= (0,1,1) 
\end{align*}
which correspond to the monomials in $\{x^2,y^2,z^2,xy,xz,yz\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose 
$$ax^2+by^2+cz^2+dxy+ezx+fyz = 0 = 0x^2+0y^2+0z^2+0xy+0zx+0yz$$
For scalars $a,b,c,d,e,f$. Then we can say right off the bat that $a=b=c=d=e=f=0$, since the coefficients of each term on both sides have to match. Two polynomials are equal if and only if their coefficients are the same.

Comment: This seems circular to me. The content of the question seems to be *why* the coefficients of each term on both sides have to match.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick The reason is that this holds *by definition*.

Comment: @egreg This depends how OP is defining multivariage polynomials. My suspicion is that OP is thinking of polynomials as *functions* rather than as formal expressions.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick I don't think so. In this particular case, there's no problem because the matrix you find has determinant $1$. If the base field is finite, for instance, the identification between (abstract) polynomials and polynomial functions is not possible. This particular case works, because by chance the determinant is $1$, but that's not guaranteed in general. The abstract point of view has been used in algebra for a long time for this reason.

Comment: @egreg I understand this. I'm simply guessing that OP isn't thinking on this level of abstraction. Since OP didn't mention a field my guess is that he or she is working over $\Bbb R$ and thinking of the collection as a collection of functions rather than of formal expressions. If the latter is indeed his or her interpretation, then I agree this is the correct (non circular) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $ax^2+by^2+cz^2 +dxy + ezx + fyz = 0$. Setting $x=y=0$ and $z=1$ gives
$$
  cz^2 = c(1)= 0,
$$
so $c=0$. Permuting the roles of $x,y,$ and $z$ shows $a=b=c=0$. Now, to get the others, set $x=y=1$ and $z=0$. Then we get
$$
 d(1)(1) + 0 + 0 = 0,
$$
so $d=0$. Then permute $x,y,$ and $z$ again and we see $d=e=f=0$.